# jQuery Animate Button Background Shape

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I am trying to duplicate the button hover effect as seen on this website: http://www.dewitt.ch/

They are using a css styled triangle and animating it across on hover.

```
jQuery(".btn")
 .mouseover(function () {
  jQuery(this).find(".triangle").animate({
    right: "-50px"
  }, 100);
 })
.mouseout(function () {
 jQuery(this).find(".triangle").animate({
    right: "-500px"
 }, 100,

 function () {
    jQuery(this).find(".triangle").css(
        "right", "100%"
    )
 });
});
```

I have created a code snippet to show my current efforts here:

```js
jQuery(".btn")
  .mouseover(function() {
    jQuery(this).find(".triangle").animate({
      right: "0px"
    });
  })
  .mouseout(function() {
    jQuery(this).find(".triangle").animate({
      right: "100%"
    });
  });
```

```css
.btn {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #d5b7a0;
  color: #d5b7a0;
  font: 400 1.2em/1em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  height: 48px;
  line-height: 48px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0 50px;
  position: relative;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  background: 0 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
}

.btn .triangle {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  border-left: 52px solid transparent;
  border-right: 52px solid transparent;
  border-top: 52px solid #d5b7a0;
  display: block;
  right: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="btn">
  <span class="triangle"></span>
  <span>Button</span>
</a>
```

I am close to getting it to work properly but the triangle shape is "bouncing", also **I'm struggling to get it to come in from the left and exit to the right.**

I am using jQuery .mouseover and .mouseout to trigger .animate which may not be the best method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the timing element that was mentioned, but what was causing the triangle element to jump around was .mouseover and .mouseout.

`.mouseenter` and `.mouseleave` work much better.

```
jQuery(".btn")
   .mouseenter(function () {
     jQuery(this).find(".triangle").animate({
        right: "-50px"
     }, 500);
   })
   .mouseleave(function () {
     jQuery(this).find(".triangle").animate({
        right: "-500px"
     }, 500,
        function () {
           jQuery(".triangle").css(
             "right", "200%"
           );
        });
});
```

Here's the code snippet:

```js
jQuery(".btn")
  .mouseenter(function() {
    jQuery(this).find(".triangle").animate({
      right: "-50px"
    }, 500);
  })
  .mouseleave(function() {
    jQuery(this).find(".triangle").animate({
        right: "-500px"
      }, 500,
      function() {
        jQuery(".triangle").css(
          "right", "200%"
        );
      });
  });
```

```css
.btn {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #d5b7a0;
  color: #d5b7a0;
  font: 400 1.2em/1em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  height: 48px;
  line-height: 48px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0 50px;
  position: relative;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  background: 0 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
}

.btn .triangle {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  border-left: 52px solid transparent;
  border-right: 52px solid transparent;
  border-top: 52px solid #d5b7a0;
  display: block;
  right: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="btn">
  <span class="triangle"></span>
  <span>Button</span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not use css:

```
.btn .triangle {
  -webkit-transition:all 0.4s ease;
  right:100%;
}

.btn:hover .triangle {
  right:0;
}
```

P.s: your jquery animate is missing the timing;

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the timing, CSS will return the background to it's original position. I'd like for it to enter from the left and exit on the right.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$( ".btn" )
  .mouseenter(function() {
    $( ".triangle" ).animate({right:"0px"}, 50);
  })
  .mouseleave(function() {
    $( ".triangle" ).animate({right:"100%"}, 50);
  });
```

Or pure css:

```
.btn .triangle {
  -webkit-transition: right 0.4s ease;
  transition: right 0.4s ease;
  right:100%;
}

.btn:hover .triangle {
  right:0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you but adding the ",50" still results in the background "bouncing"

Answer (score 0):

No need for jQuery animate on this one, CSS animation does the trick. Just remember to add css transition on the .triangle

```
.btn:hover .triangle { 
    right: 0; 
}
```

```css
.btn{
 -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
 -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
 -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
 -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
 backface-visibility: hidden;
 display: inline-block;
 border: 1px solid #d5b7a0;
 color: #d5b7a0;
 font: 400 1.2em/1em Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
 height: 48px;
 line-height: 48px;
 margin-top: 20px;
 overflow: hidden;
 padding: 0 50px;
 position: relative;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 2px;
 background: 0 0;
 cursor: pointer;
 transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
}
.btn .triangle{
 width: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 border-left: 52px solid transparent;
 border-right: 52px solid transparent;
 border-top: 52px solid #d5b7a0;
 display: block;
    right:100%;
    -webkit-transition: right 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: right 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.btn:hover .triangle {
    right: 0;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="btn">
 <span class="triangle"></span>
 <span>Button</span>
</a>
```

Comment: Thank you, but CSS will return the background to it's original position. I'd like for it to enter from the left and exit on the right.